# Rails development env dont show the error type and console on error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

My development errors look like in production.

Here how they are looking in development: 
[Production style errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Ect.png)

Instead of this error design :
[Development style errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QwfC.png)

I tried to consider all request as local in *production.rb* but this doesn't make them looking like they are supposed to look in development.

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

can someone help me to find out how to come back to the usual error development style? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your application in development mode,

use `RAILS_ENV=development rails s`

If that is not the issue check your Gemfile maybe you are using a gem for displaying errors and it is not under `group :production`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help. After an analysis of all my commits I found out it was due to a bundle update of the Gemfile.lock