# Rails Web Console and development error not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I recently updated my rails application to rails 5.2 and Ruby Version 2.3.3 to my surprise, a development error in the browser is not showing up as error anymore but with the message

`We are sorry, something went wrong
If you are the application owner please check logs`

while,

`config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

is present in my development.rb file.

and running `RAILS_ENV=development rails s` too doesn't help

And all changes I made was by following the rails guide only.

A similar thread exists with no conclusion: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797273/rails-development-env-dont-show-the-error-type-and-console-on-error-500/50529340#50529340)
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check logs in the console(terminal)?

Comment: logs are fine, I am getting the errors there, the problem is not with the error, I don't have one. The problem is that I am not having the error page in web browser, which is really helpful for debugging with the web console available

Comment: I am passing incorrect id knowingly just to get the error page, here's what I have in my log ```ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Exam with 'id'=1):
```

Comment: are you using the gem `web-console`?

Comment: @RaviMariya Yes of course .

Comment: remove it or update version, do bundle and try again

Answer (score 2):

I tried to update the 'web-console' gem and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue too, when I checked in my config/environments/development.rb the `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` was set to false.

After that for web console debugging I install `gem "better_errors"` and everything works fine. Also make sure gem `web-console` is also installed.